# Probability of distribution with gradient

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, random-walk

In the below picture, imagine that the balls are freely moving like Brownian motion. Since the box is empty and there are sufficient balls outside the box, the box will be filled eventually. Therefore, we have the boundary conditions of
$$c = 0\ (0\%), t=0\\
c = 9\ (100\%), t=\infty
$$
[image]

The motion of the balls can be simulated by random walk. However, in the regular random walk, the probabilities for all directions are the same. Here, we know that the probability towards the right (into the box) is more.

How can we simulate the process?

Comment: What do you mean with "balls go the box by the gradient"?

Comment: @Marc I meant diffusion by a concentration gradient (similar to heat flow because of temperature gradient)

Comment: @Yoria, your description is still quite un-specific. Remember, your likely audience in this section of math stack exchange are people who are knowledgeable about probability. Whilst many may understand the mathematical physics of heat flow / temperature gradients, many wont. Can you give an introduction to what you mean by this? Or an example of some of the steps from $t = 0, 1, 2$, etc. In addition (and following from my comment about $t=0,1,2$), is $t$ continuous or discrete in your context?

Comment: @owen88 I edited the question by removing the references to the physical phenomenon and focus on the probability only.

Comment: @Yoria, thank you for trying to clarify more. I think there are still many outstanding questions. **1.** Do the balls interact with (i.e. bounce off of) each other? If so this dynamic needs to be explained, and importantly this becomes a question about interacting Brownian paths / random walks which is significantly harder. **2.** How do the walls of the space come into play? Do the walks try to avoid the walls, or do they bounce off of them? This interaction will change the solution. **3.** What is the definition of filling the box? This depends again on whether balls can overlap.

Comment: @owen88 you have a subtle look at the problem, I just considered a simplified one. 1. There are interactions. 2. Yes. 3. each sub-box can accommodate one ball. To clarify the example, imagine that the balls all humans reaching empty seats. Or bees filling a beehive.

Comment: @Yoria, unfortunately you still have not posed a clearly defined question. Any solution that somebody might post would have to make assumptions of the model as you have not clearly identified them. Whatsmore, this question seems to be a rephrasing of your previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702596/numeral-calculation-based-on-gradient-probability).

Comment: @owen88 yes, I tried to present a more sensible model in this question.

Comment: @Yolanda, I appreciate your effort: what I am saying is that unfortunately given the current level of information the problem is still not fully defined, and therefore there is no clear solution.